# DTS Conversion to SSIS Derived Column Expression

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, ssis, derived-column

I've been asked to convert a DTS package to SSIS. Both of which I am relatively new to, so I'm trying to learn both and how to convert between both at the same time.

We have a couple of transformations that I'm trying to change into Derived Column Expressions, but am struggling a bit with syntax.

We pull data from an excel sheet to SQL Server.

The script we used in the DTS package is as follows:

```
Function Main()
DTSDestination("Period") = Cint(Replace(DTSSource("Period"),"Q",""))
If not IsNull(DTSSource("Annual % Change")) Then
    If cStr(DTSSource("Annual % Change")) <> "." then
        DTSDestination("% Change") = cDbl(DTSSource("Annual % Change"))
    End If
End If

Main = DTSTransformStat_OK
End Function
```

The output table is as follows:

```
[Period] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[% Change] [decimal](7, 2) NULL,
```

I believe for the Period column it should just be `(DT_I1)REPLACE([Period],"Q","")`

For the [Annual % Change] Column, I've tried to break it down, which I think goes to :

```
NOT ISNULL([Annual % Change]) 
(DT_STR,10,1252)[Annual % Change] <> "." 
(DT_R8)[Annual % Change]
```

Then in trying to build a Conditional Expression would give me:

```
ISNULL([Annual % Change]) ? NULL(DT_R8) : 
    (DT_STR,10,1252)[Annual % Change] <> "." ? (DT_R8)[Annual % Change]: NULL(DT_R8)
```

This is throwing out parsing errors, any ideas where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect these:   `NULL(DT_R8)`   What if you remove the "(DT_R8)" from it?

Comment: It still didn't like it, however it would appear that it was because my derived column wasn't being changed to match the destination data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SSIS Expression language, not equal is !=. <> doesn't work. I made that change to your expression, and it worked for me.

```
ISNULL([Annual % Change]) ? NULL(DT_R8) : 
(DT_STR,10,1252)[Annual % Change] != "." ? (DT_R8)[Annual % Change]: NULL(DT_R8)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I stumbled across this last night, I was also not matching the data types to the destination, I have just managed to get it to flow with: `(DT_DECIMAL,2)([Annual % Change] != "" ? [Annual % Change] == "." ? NULL(DT_DECIMAL,2) : (DT_DECIMAL,2)[Annual % Change] : NULL(DT_DECIMAL,2))`